# How to ensure referential integrity which relies on a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table `Level1`:

```
Id int PK
Deleted bit
```

and another table `Level2`:

```
Id
Level1id
```

I can add a `FK` to `Level2` to match the `Level1id` with `Level1.Id`
That works fine.

However, what If I want to ensure that records `INSERTed` in `Level2` *only match* records in `Level1` where the `Deleted` bit = 0 ? How do I do that?

I'm guessing that I might have to write a Trigger, but am hoping there's a more elegant solution...

Comment: Consider Inner Join and in and write your condition in where clause.

Comment: @Vijay That would work for a SELECT, but I want to prevent the record being INSERTed...

Comment: Such a FK will also prevent setting `level1.Deleted =0` if any referencing row exists. Is it what you need?

Comment: @Serg I didn't think a FK prevented value changes, it only ensured that a value being added existed in the PK of the parent table...

Comment: If no ON DELETE / ON UPDATE option is specified, FK prevents changes of the parent which cause the referencing rows to violate FK constraint

Comment: @Serg Simply changing a bit from 0 to 1 will never violate an FK constraint.

Comment: Yes, but reverse change from 1 to 0 can violate it. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's very elegant, but doable.

```
create table Level1(
    Id int not null Primary key,
    Deleted bit not null,
constraint u1 unique (Id, Deleted)
);

create table Level2(
    Id int ,
    Level1id int,
    level1Deleted bit default(1) check (level1Deleted=1),
constraint fk1 foreign key (Level1id, level1Deleted) references Level1(Id, Deleted)
);
```

Use it with a big care, one will have problems updating `level1`.

Comment: That works, Thank You. I'd like to avoid adding the level1Deleted column if possible, but I'm not sure it is...

Comment: Actually, my original question was a bit wrong.... I'll post a new question with correct requirements.