# How to ensure referential integrity which relies on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table `Level1`:

```
Id int PK
Deleted bit
```

and another table `Level2`:

```
Id int
Deleted bit
Level1id int
```

I can add a `FK` to `Level2` to match the `Level1id` with `Level1.Id` That works fine in ensuring the parent exists.

However, what If I want to ensure that records can only be `INSERTed` in `Level2` when the matching record in `Level1` has `Deleted` bit = 0 ?

Furthermore, how can I prevent the `Deleted` flag in `Level1` from being set = 1 when any child records in `Level2` have their `Deleted` bit = 0 ?
i.e. all child records must have `Deleted` = 1 before the Parent record can have `Deleted` = 1

I'm guessing that I might have to write a Trigger, but am hoping there's a more elegant solution...

Comment: You *could* achieve this with a `CONSTRAINT` by using a scalar function, however, personally I would stick to triggers. One reason is that multi-line Scalar functions aren't great performers and using them as a `CONSTRAINT` could have negative effects on your database's performance.

Comment: Perhaps a bit picky, but I think this isn't strictly "referential" integrity, it feels more like data integrity. I personally prefer to implement this in the application layer, rather than baking it into the database layer.

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to make sure the tables can only be accessed via stored procedures and do the rule checks in those.

Comment: "prevent the Deleted flag in Level1 from being set = 1 when any child records in Level2 have their Deleted bit = 0 " - this is the tricky part and it essentially reqiures locking the entire `level2` table, whichever way you choose.

Comment: This always sounds like a good idea - but eventually a situation will arise that requires the insertion of a child row where the parent is marked with a different value. It is difficult to make a schema completely fool-proof yet still flexible and responsive to unexpected situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, you could implement this logic in an application, or in stored procedures, but to do it in the database, the following functions and `CHECK` constraints should give you what you're looking for.

These will only run/check for the row you're interested in when you do an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Level1Deleted (@Id int, @Deleted bit)
RETURNS bit
AS

BEGIN

    IF @Deleted = 1

        RETURN 0

    ELSE

        RETURN
        (
            SELECT L1.Deleted
            FROM
                Level2 L2
                JOIN Level1 L1 ON L2.Level1Id = L1.Id
            WHERE L2.Id = @Id
        )

    ;

END
GO

ALTER TABLE Level2
WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Level1Deleted
CHECK (Level1Deleted(Id, Deleted) = 0)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION Level2NotFullyDeleted (@Id int, @Deleted bit)
RETURNS bit
AS

BEGIN

    IF @Deleted = 0

        RETURN 0

    ELSE

        RETURN
        (
            SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS bit)
            FROM
                Level1 L1
                JOIN Level2 L2 ON L1.Id = L2.Level1id
            WHERE
                L1.Id = @Id
                AND L2.Deleted = 0
        )

    ;

END
GO

ALTER TABLE Level1
WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Level2FullyDeleted
CHECK (Level2NotFullyDeleted(Id, Deleted) = 0)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a foreign key constraint, but you need to add some more information.

First a unique constraint that includes the bit:

```
alter table level1 add constraint unq_level1_id, deleted
    unique (delete, id);
```

Then, add a constant `0` value to `level2`

```
alter table level2 add (cast(0 as bit)) as deleted_0 persisted;
```

Then, add in the foreign key constraint:

```
alter table level2 add constraint fk_level2_id_deleted
    foreign key (level1id, deleted) references table1(id, deleted);
```

Comment: This was discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391328/how-to-ensure-referential-integrity-which-relies-on-a-value and OP decided he needs something different - allow both 0 and 1 in `level2`, but allow 1  in `level1` only when all children a set to 1.